# jinja2: How to properly format a recursive macro

Tags: recursion, macros, jinja2

I have a nested structure and a recursive macro to render it. however there is an extra empty line before all of the closing tags. How do I remove the empty lines so that is renders one contiguous block?

The data is in a form like so

```
name='...'
list
  a
  a
  b
  name='...'
  list
    b
    b
  a
```

The template is like so

```
{% macro list(item) -%}
  <ul name="{{ item.name }}">
  {% for item in item.list -%}
    {% if item.a -%}
      <li a="{{ item.a }}"/>
    {% elif item.b -%}
      <li b="{{ item.a }}">
    {% item.name -%}
      {{- list(item) }}
    {% endif -%}
  {%- endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endmacro -%}
```

The expected outcome shouldn't have this extra whitespace before the `</ul>`.

```
<ul name="...">
  <li a="a"/>
  <li a="a"/>
  <li b="b"/>
  <ul name="...">
    <li b="b"/>
    <li b="b"/>

  </ul>
  <li a="a"/>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Jinja is keeping track of linespacing why not move the statements to one line for the ending of "if" and "for" jinja declarations?

```
{% macro list(item) -%}
  <ul name="{{ item.name }}">
  {% for item in item.list -%}
    {% if item.a -%}
      <li a="{{ item.a }}"/>
    {% elif item.b -%}
      <li b="{{ item.a }}">
    {% item.name -%}
      {{- list(item) }}{% endif -%}{%- endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endmacro -%}
```